# Partial class implements interface null object

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, interface, abstract-class

Below you see the ISubject interface.  Both partial student_subject and Tutor_subject are are auto generated however these partial classes are used to allow for a parent gemeroc abstract class.

[image]

Before I pass student_Subject "sub" into new SubjectDTO(ISubject subject), it has all its properties. For example, sub.name would equal "math".

[image]

However, once I pass it to the constructor, SubjectDTO(ISubject subject) all the properties of subject are null.

[image]

Sorry If I seem new but does anyone have an idea why the object does not retain its properties.
here is the code

```
 public abstract class  ISubject
{
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography Location { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ICourse> Courses { get; set; }

}
public partial class Student_Subject :ISubject
{

    public DbSet<Student_Subject> getContext(studytree_dbEntities db)
    { return db.Student_Subject; }

}
public partial class Tutor_Subject :ISubject
{
    public DbSet<Tutor_Subject> getContext(studytree_dbEntities db)
    { return db.Tutor_Subject; }

}
```

here is the automatically generated class

```
 public partial class Student_Subject
  {
    public Student_Subject()
    {
        this.Courses = new HashSet<Student_Course>();
    }

    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Student_CourseId { get; set; }
    public System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography Location { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student_Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
}
```

Here is my StudentDTO .

```
    public class StudentDTO
     {
       public StudentDTO()
     {
         this.StudySessions = new HashSet<StudySessionDTO>();
        this.Subjects= new HashSet<SubjectDTO>();
    }
         public StudentDTO(Student s)
    {
        this.StudentId = s.StudentId;
        this.FirstName = s.FirstName;
        this.LastName = s.LastName;

        this.StudySessions = new HashSet<StudySessionDTO>();
        this.Subjects = new HashSet<SubjectDTO>();
             foreach(Student_Subject sub in s.Subjects)
             {
                 this.Subjects.Add(new SubjectDTO(sub));
             }
    }
  }
```

Subject DTO
 However when the execution comes to this class, the object has all null properties.

```
 public class SubjectDTO
 {
       public SubjectDTO()
    {
        this.Courses = new HashSet<CourseDTO>();
    }
    public SubjectDTO(ISubject subject)
       {
           this.SubjectId = subject.SubjectId;
           this.SubjectName = subject.Name;
           this.Location = subject.Location;
           this.Courses = new HashSet<CourseDTO>();
            foreach(ICourse course in subject.Courses)
            {
                this.Courses.Add(new CourseDTO(course));
            }
       }
```

Here is the exception

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   StudyTree.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.
>
> InnerException Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> StackTrace:    at StudyTree.Models.SubjectDTO..ctor(ISubject subject)
>   in c:\Users\Ethan\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\StudyTree\StudyTree\Models\SubjectDTO.cs:line 21    at
>   StudyTree.Models.StudentDTO..ctor(Student s) in
>   c:\Users\Ethan\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\StudyTree\StudyTree\Models\UserDTO.cs:line 118    at
>   StudyTree.Models.PersonDTO..ctor(Person person) in
>   c:\Users\Ethan\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\StudyTree\StudyTree\Models\UserDTO.cs:line 31    at
>   StudyTree.Repository.LoginRepository.getPersonDTO(Person p) in
>   c:\Users\Ethan\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\StudyTree\StudyTree\Repository\LoginRepository.cs:line
>   41    at MvcApplication2.Controllers.ProfileController.Login(JObject
>   j) in c:\Users\Ethan\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\StudyTree\StudyTree\Controllers\ProfileController.cs:line
>   34    at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object
>   instance, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)

Comment: Please provide code instead of images.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state you are **implementing** an interface called `ISubject` in your classes `Student_Subject` and `Tutor_Subject`. Nonetheless, this is not the case, you are truly **inherit** from an abstract class misnamed `ISubject`. The prefix `I` must *ONLY* be used for interfaces, not for abstract classes.

The issue comes from the fact you think abstract classes react like interfaces.

When **implementing** an interface, you need, to fulfill its contract, to rewrite all the code inside your class.

When **inheriting** a class (event from abstract one), you don't have to rewrite the code defined in the superclass.

You actually redefine the property `Name` in your children classes, that hides the property of the superclass. Visual Studio displays a warning about that.

> The keyword `new` is required on `Name` because its hides property `ISubject.Name`.

To correct that, just make a true interface by replacing `public abstract class  ISubject` to `public interface ISubject` and make the necessary changes in the body of the interface.